# App got crash when trying to access gcm token the time of disconnected internet

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    try {
        // In the (unlikely) event that multiple refresh operations occur simultaneously,
        // ensure that they are processed sequentially.
        synchronized (TAG) {
            // [START get_token]
            // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls
            // are local.
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

            // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
            sendRegistrationToServer(token);

            // Subscribe to topic channels
            subscribeTopics(token);

            // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
            // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
            // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
            // [END get_token]
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
        // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
        // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
    }
    // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
    Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
}
```

app got crash while accessing token by using instanceID.getToken method and device not connected to the internet.

Calling this service from manifest

```
<service
        android:name="com.sample.gcmclient.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
```

Logcat Details

```
06-03 12:50:46.070    3067-4207/? D/GCM﹕ GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService (has extras) } com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER
06-03 12:50:46.080    9974-9974/com.sample.gcmclient D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/os/Message;.sendingUid
06-03 12:50:46.080    9974-9974/com.sample.gcmclient W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve instance field 116
06-03 12:50:46.080    9974-9974/com.sample.gcmclient D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x0000
06-03 12:50:46.130    3067-4223/? W/GCM﹕ Missmatched messenger
06-03 12:50:46.170   9974-10176/com.sample.gcmclient D/RegIntentService﹕ Failed to complete token refresh
java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
        at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zzc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)
        at com.sample.gcmclient.RegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(RegistrationIntentService.java:68)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
06-03 12:50:53.080    4378-4380/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 19% free 5091K/6248K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 17ms
06-03 12:50:53.150    4378-4420/? D/Finsky﹕ [179] AppStatesReplicator.handleContentSyncResponse: Completed 0 account content syncs with 0 successful.
06-03 12:50:53.160    4378-4378/? D/Finsky﹕ [1] 5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
06-03 12:51:11.940    3350-3354/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 468K, 22% free 4985K/6344K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 18ms
```

How to fix this bug.
Thank you 
Shinurag KR

Comment: Anything on the logs ?

Comment: yes log says ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. and its not trigger the catch block.

Comment: Try sharing complete log and stacktrace

Comment: question updated with logcat details

Comment: gcm_defaultSenderId is not defined in the project. what is the value that has been filled ?

Comment: Also for refreshing tokens you need to define a `InstanceIDListenerService` as described here: https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation#refresh_tokens